# Search through Sharepoint List Items via Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a situation in which I would like to find a specific Folder inside a Sharepoint environment. So the first steps are:

1. Get User ID
2. List Side ID
3. List Side Items
4. List Items (Shared Documents) > this call results in listing every
   single item available under Shared Documents, which can be hundreds
   up till thousands. How am I able to add a search query or any other
   filter on this?

I tried with adding `?search={query}` so it would look like `/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?search={query}`
but once fired, the search is ignored. Anyone else knows how to do this as I was unable to find anything on the internet. I saw some things in relation to `'?expand='` but I don't know how this works.

Comment: Should I use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-2-search-list-items

Comment: it is solved, I used Microsoft Search API

Answer (score 1):

I used the Microsoft Search API to solve the challenge.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-2-search-list-items